# Java Treemap not incrementing properly

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to write an error logging utility for a program in work that automates tasks carried out by other products in multiple steps(It's Selenium, but I don't think that's relevant).

When a step fails for a particular task, I want to identify the step, and how many times it fails throughout a particular task (many steps are generic and repeated such as "Send Message TO X", "Update X Log" etc.)

The issue I'm facing is that when it counts an error, it's not incrementing properly. If a step fails once, it will pick it up as a count of 1. If a step fails twice, the count will remain on 1. If it fails 3 times the count will then increment to two, if 4 times it will increment to 3, and so on.

This means that if a step fails more than once my count is always off by one.
The code I'm using for this particular job is:

```
int count = map.containsKey(word) ? map.get(word) : 0;
if(word.startsWith("api") && line.contains(date.toString())){
    if (!map.containsKey(word)) {
        map.put(word, 1);
    } else {
        map.put(word, count + 1);
    }
}
```

Any pointers at all would be greatly appreciated.
Regards,
Reg.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with your if condition? i.e. `if(word.startsWith("api") && line.contains(date.toString()))`, such that there are certain conditions whereby it doesn't increment the count?

Comment: This had occurred to me as well however I can verify that this is not the case as the issue persists when these conditions are removed/altered.

Comment: I don't see any issue in your `if-else` block. Just want to confirm, your `map` is `TreeMap<String, Integer>`?

Comment: It is, sorry probably should have stated that in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

You should try changing it to

```
if (!map.containsKey(word)) {
        map.put(word, 1);
      } else {
        map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
      }
```

The variable `count` value  may be outdated during the execution. This kind of issues are best suitable for debugging. Try to track the value of `count` step by step, that will help you nail down this issue.

Comment: I will try this now and reply, thank you for your suggetion :-)

Comment: count already has the value of `map.get(word)` if `map.containsKey(word)`? Saw your edit, worth a try indeed.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't resolve the issue but I'll debug the `count` variable as suggested

Comment: Then, it definitely means that key is not actually present in the map, when you think it is.. Please check the values of the map during debugging.